# recognize user text input outside my app

Tags: java, android, text, input, service

I want to save each word the user write either inside my app or outside (when my app is either in background / not open) in local database (sqlite).
I assume I am using service that recgonize spaces / dots / enters and then capture the word before this char but how do I actually capture the word?

BTW
It might sound like some kind of malicious app, it isnt. I want to make
some kind of dictionary.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the only way is to create a keyboard app and, once the user sets your as the default keyboard, save words in the database

Comment: Ow, thats suck =(
thank you for your answer!

Comment: yeah..btw wait if someone else knows the solution. I commented instead of answering because I was not sure 100%. gl!